# iOS - Swift - Accessibility VoiceOver problem with a UICollectionView and ScrollToItemAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uiaccessibility

I have a problem involving a UICollectionView or a UITableView and the accessibility.
The flow is as follows.
Loading the viewcontroller, I perform a scrollToItemAtIndexPath to display a specific cell as the first item.
I activate the voice over with the reading of the elements of the view in succession.
When it has to read the collectionview, instead of reading the indexpath I moved to, it always reads the indexPath 0.

How can I make it automatically read at first the element I want?

Thanks

Manuela